UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 31: invalid start byte
I'm encountering this error only on file in a list of seemingly identical files. My code is as follows:
data_dir = 'C:/Users\ebook\Downloads\Batch One Set\Sample Output'

for filepath in (os.listdir(data_dir)):
    splitstr = filepath.split('.')
    title = splitstr[0]
    metadata = pandas.read_csv(data_dir + '/' + filepath, nrows = 60)

The error occurs in the pandas.read_csv funtion.
Everything is fine and dandy for the previous files, such as "Patient 3-1.csv" "Patient 34-1.csv" etc. but on "Patient 35-1.csv" this error flips up. Any ideas why?
UPDATE: file contains strange characters, especially the degree one
"TOS - R Digit 3 (^13014669E 90° ^13014670E)"
any advice on encodings that might resolve this?
Setting encoding='unicode_escape', encoding='latin1' and changing engine='python' does not fix the issue.
Update: Upgrading Pandas to latest version (2.0.3) and encoding = 'latin1' solved the issue.

encoding="latin1", perhaps?

@nneonneo is probably right.  Have you looked at the file to see what it's complaining about?

tried "encoding="latin1" , same error. @nneonneo

file looks fine at first glance, matches the previous ones that worked @TimRoberts

on second glance, the file does contain strange symbols, notably the degree one:
TOS - R Digit 3 (^13014669E 90° ^13014670E) - AC PPG (%)
any advice on how to fix? @TimRoberts

You used a forward slash for windows path? data_dir = 'C:/Users\ebook\Downloads\Batch One Set\Sample Output'

or @nneonneo? any ideas on the ° character?

I guess you could try encoding_errors='backslashreplace' or something. It's really unlikely that you could get the same error with encoding="latin1" as that is capable of decoding any 8-bit byte. You might want to check that you're not tripping up elsewhere...

It is Latin-1.  The degree symbol is 0xB0 in Latin-1.  So, you could not be seeing the same error.

It's Windows, so more likely one of the Windows-125x encodings.  Windows-1252 if using a US Windows locale.  But definitely not the same error of 'utf8' codec can't decode....

@nneonneo i figured it out, turns out my pandas version was severely outdated, still 1.xx. Updating pandas and its dependencies fixed the issue, although I'm not entirely sure why - maybe new feature, or bugfix, etc.
Using encoding = 'latin1' works now.
